# Visa ban/ British passport application

Tags: passports, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

I have been refused a UK visa because of a fake immigration stamp.
The picture attached is the document I was given.
However, I am a British citizen by descent but haven't made applications for my passport.. 
Is this an outright ban and can I still apply for a British passport or does this affect my British passport applications?[image]

Comment: `British citizen by descent` So why were you applying for a visa ? Your fake entry/exit stamps seems quite shady. Why are they in your passport ? From the last paragraph it seems the 10 year ban is in force now. Not sure how your passport applications will be entertained, but your current ban will be available to the officer deciding your citizenship application.

Comment: @DumbCoder the stamps may be shady, but if OP is indeed a British citizen, there's not much standing in the way of a passport application or the exercise of the right of abode.

Comment: @phoog You never know what can count under the good character option. Visa by deception and a ban will likely make a difficult case for approval.

Comment: @DumbCoder what good character option?

Comment: Aha I forgot the OP is a citizen. But it is still weird, why apply for a visa when the cost for applying for a visa is the same as for a passport.

Comment: You can bet that they are going to very carefully scrutinize the application for a passport.

Comment: What were you even thinking by getting so many stamps on the same day?

Comment: If OP is a British citizen, then visas are a waste of time, British citizens *don't need visas* and *cannot be refused at Heathrow*.  Focus 100% on proving the citizenship.  [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) applies.

Comment: Right now, OP's credibility is shot, given the fact that there are at least 8 supposedly counterfeit visa stamps on the passport.  At this point, nobody in the Home Office or any government office in the UK is going to believe the OP

Comment: @MatthewBarclay They will surely give extra scrutiny to the documents submitted to support the claim of British citizenship, but beyond that it doesn't matter whether they believe the OP; it just matters whether they can establish that the documents are false.

Comment: @greatone considering that one can drive from Ghana to Nigeria in three to four hours, passing through Togo and Benin, it's not so surprising that someone would have so many stamps on a single day.

Comment: @phoog Possible. I wonder what the OP intended by so many fraudulent stamps and also how the UKVI found out. Perhaps he was in the UK during this time and wanted to hide that?

Comment: @greatone or maybe the OP wanted to fake a trip from Ghana to Nigeria or vice versa for some completely different reason unrelated to the UK, but the UK identified the fake stamps because the shapes, the ink, or the serial numbers were incorrect.  Who can say?  It doesn't make much of a difference for the present question, however.

Comment: Going forward, what steps can OP take towards applying for a passport, should an immigration lawyer be engaged?

Comment: @Ayobamidele if you are indeed a British citizen, I doubt a lawyer would be necessary unless the evidence supporting your claim of citizenship is questionable or the UK government declines to accept it for any reason.  Just apply for the passport.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are indeed a British citizen, by descent or otherwise, then the provisions of the Immigration Act 1971 pertaining to foreign citizens do not apply to you.  The portion [defining the offence of deception](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/77/section/24A) begins:

> A person who is not a British citizen is guilty of an offence if...

Furthermore, deception as a ground for refusal is defined in the Immigration Rules.  [Part 9](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal) concerns "General grounds for the refusal of entry clearance, leave to enter or variation of leave to enter or remain in the United Kingdom (paragraphs A320 to 324)."  None of that has to do with passport applications.

There is a [policy document about refusal of passport applications](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/refusing-and-withdrawing-passport-facilities-and-withdrawal-of-applications).  It says nothing about deception.

There is also a [document describing the issue of passports as an exercise of royal prerogative](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118554/royal-prerogative.pdf).  This document suggests that your passport will be granted unless your

> past or proposed activities are so demonstrably undesirable that the grant or continued enjoyment of passport facilities would be contrary to the public interest (these cases are very rare and decisions on this category are made personally by the Home Secretary);

Comment: can i go ahead and send in an application for a passport?

Comment: @Ayobamidele yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re a British citizen by descent, then it’s odd that you went through the visa process when you could have instead obtained a genuine British passport (possibly even for less money and/or with less admin than for a visa).

If you’re a British citizen by descent, then you can apply for a British passport. You will need to provide documentation pertaining to your parents, and possibly also your grandparents.

You can start your application here: https://www.gov.uk/apply-renew-passport

If you have a genuine right to citizenship by descent, then this right is unaffected by any criminal activity or denied visas. But you can be sure they will take a hard look at your application.